# too few arguments to function 'void setColor(int, int, int)'

Tags: serial

When I put "c" inside `setColor(c);`

it tells me:

```
error: too few arguments to function 'void setColor(int, int, int)'.
```

I understand that I should put 3 arguments. What I don't understand is that the serial is correctly displaying the 3 arguments (255, 000, 000) so why it keeps telling me this error. What am I doing wrong ?

```
int rPin = 11;
int gPin = 9;
int bPin = 10;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(rPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(gPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(bPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            delay(100);
            while (Serial.available() > 0) {
                char c = Serial.read(); // serial will display an rgb code, for exemple: 255, 000, 000 (red color) 
                setColor(c);
            }
        }
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
    analogWrite(rPin, red);
    analogWrite(gPin, green);
    analogWrite(bPin, blue);
}
```

Comment: You understand that `c` can only contain a single character, right?

Comment: `c` is what the serial is displaying, in this case an rgb code like `255, 000, 000` am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of C/C++, the type `char` refers to a primitive type that can contain exactly one byte of information, or 8 bits if you like.

> the serial is correctly displaying the 3 arguments (255, 000, 000)

In your question, you do not specify how you verify that this is indeed the information that returns from Serial.read. [Serial.read](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/read) returns one byte, which can be cast or parsed to an Integer but cannot be interpreted as the triplet (255,000,000) in no way. If you keep calling it repeatedly, however, as long as there is data (meaning that the result is greater than -1 or `Serial.available` returns a number greater than 0) - you can accumulate the characters to a meaningful string, which you can later split to three different `int` values. For example:

```
String incomingData = "";

void loop() 
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
         delay(100);
         while (Serial.available() > 0) {
             char c = Serial.read(); 
             incomingData.concat(c);
         }

         // now, the string incomingData will contain "255,000,000" which you can split into 3 different integers and send to setColor. 
         // so, assuming the format "ddd,ddd,ddd":

         int color1 = incomingData.substring(0,3).toInt();
         int color2 = incomingData.substring(4,7).toInt();
         int color3 = incomingData.substring(8).toInt();
         setColor(color1, color2, color3);
    }
}
```

Comment: This result in error `error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int atoi(const char*)'`

Comment: please see my edit.

Comment: now it tells me `error: 'setColor' was not declared in this scope` by the way I forgot to mention that I am totally beginner at C++ and i'm very grateful for your help. I'm actually studying you piece of code. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. The code above is not complete; do not forget to include the 'setColor' function which I omitted.

Comment: Ok It works but I need to make some tweaking, I need to make some adjustments, including the fact that I can not change the color without reloading the script. Thank you Omer.